# How to show open folds?

Tags: vim, vim-folding

How can I show open folds in vim?  (i.e., folds that are currently open)

e.g., show the open folds within the text somehow, like marking the lines;
or perhaps show them as a list (e.g., like the `:jumps` command that shows a list of jumps)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know that folds can be listed, but marking of lines is possible using the `foldcolumn` option. (`:help 'foldcolumn'`). Try

```
set foldcolumn=12
```

Caveat: per the documentation, if `nofoldenable` is set, open folds will *not* be shown in the `foldcolumn`.
`[foldenable] can be toggled with the *zi* command.  The 'foldcolumn' will remain blank when 'foldenable' is off.`  [*:help foldenable*]